# Adding a variable to a list of data.frames using magrittr syntax

Tags: r, magrittr

Say you have a list of data.frames that already exist in the environment:

```
library(magrittr)
lapply(
  paste0("z", 2011:2015),
  function(x) assign(
    x, 
    data.frame(x=rnorm(10),y=rnorm(10)),
    pos = 1
  )
)
# should create z2011 through z2015 in your R env
```

What I would like to do is: extract a column, combine these into one data.frame, then add an additional variable to identify where they came from using magrittr syntax.

I realize this is something trivial using other techniques (namely:  `ldply(list)`, `rbind.fill(listing)`, `rbind_all(listing)`, `do.call(rbind,...)`). The point of my question is to understand approaches using `magrittr` syntax.

```
df <- 
   paste0("z",2011:2015) %>%
   lapply(get) %>%
   lapply(function(x) extract2(x,"x")) %>%
   # what would you do next? Another approach you think is
   # more appropriate for magrittr?
```

I don't know how to add a new variable. For examples sake, I would like to end up with the following:

```
do.call(
  rbind, 
  lapply(
    paste0("z",2011:2015), 
    function(x) {
      data.frame(x = get(x)$x, year = x)
    }
  )
)
```

Comment: I would do `df <- 
    paste0("z",2011:2015) %>%
    lapply(get) %>% lapply(function(x) x[["x"]]) %>% as.data.frame() %>% set_names(paste0("z", 2011:2015)) %>% melt` but it isn't very idiomatic

Answer (score 0):

I've always thought that you get `magrittr`-idiomatic approach by taking nested calls and turning them inside out. So, doing that to the last snippet of yours yields

```
paste0("z", 2011:2015) %>%
  lapply(function(name) data.frame(x = get(name)$x, year = name)) %>% 
  do.call(rbind, .)
```

which looks fine to me. I'm not a huge fan of breaking every possible statement down to `x %>% foo1 %>% foo2 %>% ...`, and in this situation this is additionally justified: otherwise you'll have to repeat `paste0` call again to reconstruct variable names (as proposed in the comment).

Answer (score 0):

**data**

First I'll make your example a bit shorter for better readability.

```
# creates data.frames z2011, z2012 and z2013, 2 lines each
lapply(
  paste0("z", 2011:2013),
  function(x) assign(
    x, 
    data.frame(x=rnorm(2),y=rnorm(2)),
    pos = 1
  )
)
```

**`magrittr` + `base` solution**

You should never use `lapply(get(x))`, use `mget` instead.
And you should use `extract` and not `extract2` in your `lapply` as you wish to keep a `data.frame`.

Then the idiomatic `magrittr` way of assigning a column is to use `inset` or `inset2` (same effect here)

So you get :

```
mget(paste0("z",2011:2015)) %>%
  lapply(extract,"x") %>%
  Map(inset,.,"year",value = names(.)) %>%
  do.call(rbind,.)

#                   x  year
# z2011.1 -0.62124058 z2011
# z2011.2 -2.21469989 z2011
# z2012.1 -0.01619026 z2012
# z2012.2  0.94383621 z2012
# z2013.1  0.91897737 z2013
# z2013.2  0.78213630 z2013
```

**using `purrr`**

`magrittr` is often used with `tidyverse`, using only `purrr::map_dfr` you could write:

```
library(purrr)
mget(paste0("z",2011:2013)) %>%
  map_dfr(~.["x"],.id="year")

#    year           x
# 1 z2011 -0.62124058
# 2 z2011 -2.21469989
# 3 z2012 -0.01619026
# 4 z2012  0.94383621
# 5 z2013  0.91897737
# 6 z2013  0.78213630
```